# How To Change Each Parent Child Component Text More Effecient ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I finding the more effecient code to find each child from parent gameobject and change each child component Text of gameobject.

Each child component Text of gameobject have a different value of each depend from the variable.

This is the screenshot[image]

This is my code :

```
public Dictionary <string, GameObject> product = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    public Dictionary <string, Text> property = new Dictionary<string, Text> ();

dex = productMargaret.FindIndex(j => j.productID == 15);
            product["Mayonnaise"] = GameObject.Find("btnMayonnaise");

            property["qty"] = gameObject.transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<Text> (); //+ productMargaret[dex].qty.ToString;
            property["qty"].text = productMargaret[dex].qty.ToString;
            property["price"] = gameObject.transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<Text> (); //+ productMargaret[dex].price.ToString;
            property["price"].text = "@ " + productMargaret[dex].price.ToString;
            property["have"] =  gameObject.transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<Text> (); //+ productMargaret[dex].have.ToString;
            property["have"].text = "You Have : " + productMargaret[dex].have.ToString;
```

Thats code is not working.

How to do it ? for effecient way like maybe use a looping.

Thanks

Comment: I found the solution myself. This two video explain all about the problem [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjFsrVWQaQw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjFsrVWQaQw) [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL36b6lo4-k](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL36b6lo4-k)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your buttons are named something like btnProductID_15, btnProductID_16, btnProductID_17 and have Button component attached to them. You could simply do something like on a parent gameObject:

```
public Dictionary <string, string> property = new Dictionary<string, Text> (); //the Key would be btnProductID_15...btnProductID_N and value will be the label of the button.
List<Button> btnList = GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
foreach (Button item in btnList)
{
   Text textField = GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
   textField.text = property[item.name];
}
```

Ofcourse you are going to have the populate the "property" dictionary accordingly....And now am hungry.